# Show three divs when clicking on on button using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have seven names, and I want to only show three presentations when I click on a name, with the selected name in the middle. As it is now, all divs loads first and then hide.

When I click the first name, the three divs shows. But when I click button four, and then go back to the first name, it's only showing two divs.

I haven't done any coding so far on the other names, I thought that if I can get the first name/button to work I can figure out the rest.

It's a wordpress site and I use Divi to build my pages.

I have in on this page: http://demo.konstuppsala.online/est/

My code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide the div 1
    jQuery('#reveal1').hide();
    
    jQuery('.rv_button1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#reveal1").slideToggle();
        jQuery('.rv_button1').toggleClass('opened closed');
        
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#reveal2").slideToggle();
        jQuery('.rv_button2').toggleClass('opened closed');
        
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#reveal6").slideToggle();
        jQuery('.rv_button6').toggleClass('opened closed');
        
        jQuery("#reveal1").animate({left: '500px'});
        jQuery('#reveal2').show();
        jQuery("#reveal2").animate({left: '50px'});
        jQuery('#reveal3').hide();
        jQuery('#reveal4').hide();
        jQuery('#reveal5').hide();
        jQuery('#reveal6').show();
        jQuery("#reveal6").animate({right: '50px'});    
    });
});

the HTML:
<div id="reveal1">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
  <h4 class="et_pb_module_header"><span>Anna-Karin</span></h4>
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_description"><p>Test med att visa/dölja en blurb<br /><img loading="lazy" class="wp-image-97 alignnone size-thumbnail" src="http://media.demo.konstuppsala.online/2020/12/katter_-10-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></p>
<h4><strong>1</strong></h4></div>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 

<div id="reveal2">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
  <h4 class="et_pb_module_header"><span>Anna-Karin</span></h4>
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_description"><p>Test med att visa/dölja en blurb<br /><img loading="lazy" class="wp-image-97 alignnone size-thumbnail" src="http://media.demo.konstuppsala.online/2020/12/katter_-10-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></p>
<h4><strong>1</strong></h4></div>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 

<div id="reveal3">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
  <h4 class="et_pb_module_header"><span>Anna-Karin</span></h4>
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_description"><p>Test med att visa/dölja en blurb<br /><img loading="lazy" class="wp-image-97 alignnone size-thumbnail" src="http://media.demo.konstuppsala.online/2020/12/katter_-10-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></p>
<h4><strong>1</strong></h4></div>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Does this help? The problem is that I followed a tutorial so I don't have a pure mockup to show.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include any relevant HTML too to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can create a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) right in your question that will run JS so we can see an example of how your code is working now.

Comment: Or you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://repl.it/

Comment: Do you have any sort of image mockup that describes the behavior?

Comment: I have this, but it's another code which I can't get to work with Divi.
http://demo.konstuppsala.online/toggle.html  

I need to consider that people who are not programmers need to be able to change the names and information in the divs.

Comment: Questions posted on SO should be self-contained, meaning external links should supplement the question, but not be required to understand/answer it. So please add any relevant HTML _to the question itself_ so we can see this functionality, rather than only linking to an external site.

Comment: @lost_in_magento Stackoverflow has its own Stack Snippets which keeps the question self contained, so it's _much_ better to use them than jsfiddle. One may want to still use repl.it for _other_ languages, but I wouldn't recommend people use jsfiddle any more for anything a stack snippet can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the desired behavior using a simpler markup for simplicity [here](https://codepen.io/lual/pen/RwGBgzd). The JS snippet is this:

```js
const reset = () => {
  $(".options").children().hide();
};

const showSelected = e => {
  const n = Number(e.target.getAttribute("data-n")) + 1;
  $(`.option:nth-child(${n - 1})`).show();
  $(`.option:nth-child(${n})`).show();
  $(`.option:nth-child(${n + 1})`).show();
};

const showOption = e => {
  reset();
  showSelected(e);
};

const main = () => {
  $(".button").click(e => showOption(e));
};

$(document).ready(main());
```

### Notice that:

- Instead of using JS to hide the initial elements, you can simply apply `display: none;` to the class that you assigned to the boxes.
- Instead of listening to a click event triggered by a specific button, you can just listen to the click event coming from any of the buttons in the header, and then use the [event target](https://devdocs.io/dom/event/target) plus a [custom `data-n` attribute](https://devdocs.io/html/global_attributes/data-*) to determine which box is actually being selected.
- I cheated a little bit adding extra boxes at both ends. Another approach would be to rearrage the boxes dynamically.

### Syntax Notes

- I used [arrow functions](https://devdocs.io/javascript/functions/arrow_functions) instead of the `function` keyword, and `$` instead of `jQuery` because of a matter of taste. The code should work if you use the alternative style.